# Memory Leak - Writing to files in a loop

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-leaks, file-writing

I am fairly new to android development and I'm having trouble debugging memory leaks. I have tried using the Memory Allocation Tracking tool on Android Studio and found this... [Memory Allocation Tracking Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dExqm.png)

Using this tool pointed that the majority of my memory allocation come from this line:

```
String dataJSON = dataMapAsJSONObject(data).toString() + "\n";
```

and this one:

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(stream);
```

Keep in mind, this code is ran in a loop, approximately once every second. Here is the full code below... Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```
private void saveData(DataMap data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "saveData");
    if (!isExternalStorageWritable()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "External Storage Not Writable");
        return;
    }
    File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    directory.mkdirs();
    File file = null;
    if (data.containsKey("Counts")) { // This is a pretty bad way of doing this..
        file = new File(directory, "acc_count_data.txt");
    } else {
        file = new File(directory, "wearable_data.txt");
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to log to file: " + file.getPath());

    String dataJSON = dataMapAsJSONObject(data).toString() + "\n";
    try {
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(stream);
        writer.write(dataJSON);
        writer.close();
        stream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error Saving");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can always write it as `writer.write(dataMapAsJSONObject(data).toString()); writer.write("\n");` - that saves basically doubling the amount of memory you use to store the string's JSON representation.

Comment: Resource clean up should be done in the finally block.

Comment: Those lines cause allocations, but neither are a leak (well, unless the dataMapAsJSONObject call has a leak inside of it).  There's a difference between the two.  Although you need to be more careful on your closing of streams in case of an exception.

Comment: @GabeSechan true, but OP states "the majority of my memory allocation comes from this line" - perhaps the allocations on that line simply swamp the ones where the leak occurs. There's no harm in reducing them.

Comment: You also might be able to do something to avoid converting `data` to a string and then writing it - I don't know how you are converting it to JSON, but there is possibly a way of doing it directly to a writer.

Comment: @CodeCody What do you mean? I'm not very experienced with this..

Comment: finally{ writer.close(); stream.close(); }

Comment: read up on the try,catch and finally blocks.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank you. I'm really confused by this... the OutputStreamWriter line is 38% of my memory allocation. I don't understand why.

Comment: how long is it taking to execute dataMapAsJSONObject(data).toString() + "\n" ?

Comment: @CodeCody technically (at least without try-with-resources), those should be in separate try/finally blocks: an exception in creating the writer would be outside the try, meaning that the `stream` wouldn't be closed. Alternatively, you could do the `stream = null; writer = null; try { } finally { if (stream != null) stream.close(); ... }` nonsense that t-w-r did away with.

Comment: I get an error with this [new code](http://i.imgur.com/N17sQ64.png).